# Import .txt file to matlab, anything works

Tags: matlab

I have a problem importing data to matlab workspace. My file is a .txt file with 8 columns and a lot of rows (I cannot count them). The first 5 columns are numbers, but the 3 last are paths (letters), each path indicates the position of an image that correspond to the first 5 datas. 
I want to save the whole file into a matrix, I have tried load (but it doesn't work when I mixed characters), textscan (but it gives me just a row vector), impordata (but only write the first column data), fscan.... I think I have tried every command, and still doesn't work.

I want to specify that the text I have is another variable I want to save to work with it in a future, is not a headline.

Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A matrix can only store number, I think that you need a cell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Txt import in Matlab, different row formats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813666/txt-import-in-matlab-different-row-formats)

Comment: I don't have a headline, I want my text to be another variable to work with it in a future. obchardon already solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store your data into a cell, not a matrix, textscan should work without any problems

```
fileID = fopen('file.txt');
C = textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f %f %f %s %s %s');
fclose(fileID);
```

If you have a particular delimiter between your column you can specify this delimiter:

```
C = textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f %f %f %s %s %s','Delimiter','|')
```

Comment: I have try your lines and matlab reads C as a 1x8 cell, each cell contains a 2149x1 double data, and if I click on it, it shows a row vector with my data. But I want matlab to show my data has a table, so I can take any data I want. Is there any way to take the datas from C so I can give a row and colum position to take the datas I want?

Comment: [Access Data in a Cell](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html)

Comment: Matlab is not a DBMS so you won't found the same concept of table.

Comment: @obchardon actually matlab does have a `table` structure, as well as (presumably more relevant to this) a `dataset` structure. Both allow you to "query" your dataset using a column 'name' etc.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Woooo cool I didn't know about this functionality !

Comment: yes it gets fairly overlooked :p  The other useful one is the `categorical` class. Very useful for doing something like `a = categorical({'male','female','other'}); a == 'male'` where trying to do this with strings would lead to a lot of complications.